# Can I use `chmod` to change the permission from -rwsr-xr-x to -rwsr-sr-x?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Can I use `chmod` to change the permission from -rwsr-xr-x to -rwsr-sr-x?

Answer (score 6):

```
chmod g+s filename
```

Answer (score 2):

yes....the chmod command to use is

```
 chmod 6755 file1 ... filen
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, `chmod` allows any permissions changes on any file you own on a writable medium, including adding setgid.  To do this, use:

```
chmod g+s <file>
```

The `g+s` sets the setgid bit on the file.

You can also specify the full permissions of the file:

```
chmod 6755 <file>
```

This changes the permissions of the file to `-rwsr-sr-x`.

In both cases, replace `<file>` with the actual name of the file.  You can perform this operation on multiple files by putting more than one file name on the command line in place of `<file>`.

For more information on `chmod` and UNIX filesystem permissions, see the Wikipedia articles on [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [filesystem permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions).